# Alternative for 'CharIndex' in SQL

Tags: sql

I've a sql table in which one of the column 'Codes' consists of multiple character values sperated by '|'.

(For ex.:|0000000171|0000001192|0000003498|0000003569|).

Now in a query inorder to check a single value if it exists in the colum 'Codes', One row is succesfully returned if I use:-

```
charindex('0000000171', Codes) > 0
```

**Question**:- What could be the correct query in SQL if I want to 
search more than one value, if any of them exist in column 'Codes'.

For ex. If need to search the existence of three values 0000000171, 0000000172, 0000000173 in column 'Codes', following syntax return Nothing:-

```
charindex('0000000171,0000000172,0000000173', Codes) > 0
```

Please advice ...

Comment: Fix your database structure to store the codes in a separate table.  A delimiated list stored in a text field is a good sign that the table structure needs to be revisited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
(charindex('0000000171', Codes) > 0
or
charindex('0000000172', Codes) > 0
or
charindex('0000000173', Codes) > 0)
```

Comment: Yes aF.. I have already thought this solution and it is my last option. Please let me know if any other shorter alternative is there.

Comment: @Kings You're having to work around bad design (i.e. the codes should have been stored in a separate table as Gordon Linoff mentioned). That's why there is (probably) no easier solution.

Comment: @MichaelTodd - You are correct. Point noted and understood. Thnx : )

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use a delimited list, then your charindex should include the delimited on each code, as in:

```
charindex('|'+'0000000171'+'|', Codes) > 0
```

or

```
charindex('|0000000171|', Codes) > 0
```

Whoever designed the "Codes" field seemed to have this in mind, since it begins and ends with a delimiter.

However, the right solution is to store the codes in a separate table.

Comment: Gordon - Thanks much for the suggesting the probable alternative and reason for it. I will use the basic Answer provided here. Rest remains on re-designing the table structure.

Comment: I understand.  I've stored things in delimited lists more than once.  However, you see where this leads, and it's usually not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charindex` three times

```
charindex('0000000171', Codes) > 0 or
charindex('0000000172', Codes) > 0 or
charindex('0000000173', Codes) > 0
```

Comment: Mikael - Can you suggest any other shorter alternative. The solution you suggested and also by aF is indeed a correct way to acheive the objective. I wonder if any inbuilt functionality is there.

Comment: Using `like` will be 28 characters shorter. `Codes like '%0000000171%' or Codes like '%0000000172%' or Codes like '%0000000173%'` I don't know of any built in functions that can do this for you.

Comment: ya, got the point. The answer provided is the only correct one. The only proper alternative is to redesign table structure, A big task :P. thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: Yes, that would be the best alternative.